# Toggle(show/hide) components onClick in single page React component useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

How do you toggle between components in the single page case below? Ideally, when you click the `menu-item` the associated component will show and the others will hide.

**React**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import About from "./components/About";
import Projects from "./components/Projects";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";

const App = () => {
    // Toggle state(s) here?

    // Toggle function(s) here?

    return (
        <div className="nav">
            <ul className="menu">
                <li className="menu-item">About</li>
                <li className="menu-item">Projects</li>
                <li className="menu-item">Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
            <About />
            <Projects />
            <Contact />
        </div>
    )
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way is to render a component based on the current state and change the state to render another component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import About from "./components/About";
import Projects from "./components/Projects";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";

const App = () => {
    const [page, setPage] = useState("about")

    return (
        <div className="nav">
            <ul className="menu">
                <li className="menu-item" onClick={() => setPage("about")}>About</li>
                <li className="menu-item" onClick={() => setPage("projects")}>Projects</li>
                <li className="menu-item" onClick={() => setPage("contact")}>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
            {page === "about" && <About />}
            {page === "projects" && <Projects />}
            {page === "contact" && <Contact />}
        </div>
    )
};

export default App;
```

You probably want to make it a little cleaner but you have the idea.

Comment: {page === "about" && <About />} this thing is not a good code. What if we have 50-100 components? For every new component, we have to write this kind of condition and this is very bad!

Comment: Then you should use routers or create your own router. Or create a separate component just to handle these types of conditions based on your application state. This is just an example of how you can condition your renders based on your state, not an example of how you should write the code and structure your project. @HardikChaudhary

Comment: This will do very well for me, can't find a better example. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can manage an array for menu items and selected component will render!
Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/hardik-chaudhary/pen/QWwmEZK) demo!

```
const About=()=>"About us page";
const Projects=()=>"Projects page";
const Contact=()=>"Contact Page";
const App = () => {
   const menuItems =[
    {component:<About />, title:"About"},
    {component:<Projects />, title:"Projects"},
    {component:<Contact />, title:"Contact"}
   ];

   const [component, setComponent] = React.useState(menuItems[0].component);

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="nav">
            <ul className="menu">
                {
                  menuItems.map((item,i)=>
                    <li key={i} onClick={()=>setComponent(item.component)} className="menu-item">
                      {item.title}
                    </li>
                  )
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
           {component}
        </div>
       </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```